# How do I speed up my sqlite3 queries in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an sqlite table with a few hundred million rows:

```
sqlite> create table t1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,stuff TEXT );
```

I need to query this table by its integer primary key hundreds of millions of times. My code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('stuff.db')
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for id in ids:
        try:
            cur.execute("select stuff from t1 where rowid=?",[id])
            stuff_tuple = cur.fetchone()
            #do something with the fetched row
        except:
            pass #for when id is not in t1's key set
```

Here, ids is a list that may have tens of thousands of elements. Forming t1 did not take very long (ie ~75K inserts per second). Querying t1 the way I've done it is unacceptably slow (ie ~1K queries in 10 seconds).

I am completely new to SQL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I have an sqlite table with a few hundred million rows". Unless you absolutely need to stick to SQLite you should drop it and use real database. SQLite is not meant to handle such amount of data efficiently.

Comment: Interesting, any suggestions? I was originally just using a dict, but it turns out that I will have too much data to fit in RAM. I figured SQLite was the way to go.

Comment: I don't want to start the usual dispute, but any of MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle should do just fine. What's important they allow you to fine tune their performance characteristics and also split the load across multiple machines. Simply put you have enterprise-grade amount of data, so you should use enterprise-grade database engine. If you're on linux I'd recommend using PostgreSQL, I've used it for handling large datasets and it worked fine. There's also a good book about fine tuning it - http://www.amazon.com/PostgreSQL-High-Performance-Gregory-Smith/dp/184951030X (NO affiliation)

Comment: If you were using a dict, then it seems that you don't need a relational database. Perhaps a simple key-value store will do? You may want to look into [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org).

Comment: I will look into it. I am completely new to databases. I just need fast lookups on about 10-20GB of text.

Comment: Redis or Mongdb or any nosql databases are easy to setup and maintain.  If you are using any of the relational databases, you will have to create a schema but you could write stored procedures and not write queries in python code.

Comment: @voithos is right, that NoSQL might be better in your case. But in case of Redis once your dataset doesn't fit in RAM you'll experience very poor performance. Haven't used CouchDB so can't comment on that.

Comment: @kgr: Ah, yes. I had a suspicion that Redis was in-memory, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: If you did want to use a dict and did not want to install anything, check out [anydbm](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html) which allows a key-value database and the best thing is its built into python

Comment: @voithos I ended up using Redis. If you want to make that an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @rcompton: Nice! Just wondering, has the in-memory nature of Redis been a problem?

Comment: @voithos not a problem, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're retrieving values by their keys, it seems like a key/value store would be more appropriate in this case. Relational databases (Sqlite included) are definitely feature-rich, but you can't beat the performance of a simple key/value store.

There are several to choose from:

- [Redis](http://redis.io/): "advanced key-value store", very fast, optimized for in-memory operation
- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/): extremely high performance, scalable, used by multiple high-profile sites
- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/): feature-rich, tries to be "middle ground" between relational and NoSQL (and they've started offering [free online classes](https://education.10gen.com))

And there's [many, many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_store).

Answer (score 0):

You should make one sql call instead, should be must faster

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('stuff.db')
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for row in cur.execute("SELECT stuff FROM t1 WHERE rowid IN (%s)" % ','.join('?'*len(ids)), ids):
        #do something with the fetched row
        pass
```

you do not need a try except since ids not in the db will not show up. If you want to know which ids are not in the results, you can do:

```
ids_res = set()
for row in c.execute(...):
    ids_res.add(row['id'])
ids_not_found = ids_res.symmetric_difference(ids)
```